# Buffer binding using OpenGL and GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I wonder if there is a way to bind a Texture Buffer (TBO) Object directly on a certain range of data like it's possible to do using Uniform Buffer object (UBO -> glBindBufferRange).

Actually, I store my matrices within a TBO and to recover each of them within my vertex shader I need to send an 'GLUint' offset as Uniform variable. So, I wonder if it's possible to make a "kind of glBindBufferRange" applied on my TBO. This way I won't need to send each time for each vertex shader the offset where my matrices are stored.

I did a lot of researches on the subject and I did not found any concluding information (just glTexBufferRange but this function does not seem to be used for this purpose...).

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: `glTexBufferRange()` sounds like it would do what you're describing. Can you elaborate on how it does not meet your needs, and what is different about what you're trying to do?